Option Style Definitions Not Grabbing CurrentValue["MouseOver"]
I created a private stylesheet for a notebook that makes Section style cells appear bold when moused over.  Here is the private stylesheet.
Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]]
Cell[StyleData["Section"],
FontWeight->If[
   CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Bold, Plain]]

The issue is that the mouseover code is removed when I try to grab these style definitions programmatically.
Options[InputNotebook[], StyleDefinitions]

Yields...
{StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Section"], FontWeight -> Bold]}, 
   WindowSize -> {808, 911}, 
   WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 30}, {Automatic, 0}}, 
   FrontEndVersion -> 
    "14.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 12, 2023)", 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]}

Notice that the mouseover is gone.  How can I programmatically obtain the stylesheet definitions without losing it?

Can't test this at the moment, but the easiest way is probably to specify the option using :> instead of -> (i.e. FontWeight:>If[…])

As explained by @LukasLang in the comment, you have to make sure that your If statement is not evaluated only once. If you use Rule, your If will immediately evaluate to either Plain or Bold, depending on your current mouse position:
Style["Test", FontWeight -> If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Bold, Plain]] // InputForm
(* Style["Test", FontWeight -> Bold] *)

However, if you use RuleDelayed, your If will remain there, and it will be evaluated every time "something changes", roughly speaking:
Style["Test", FontWeight :> If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Bold, Plain]] // InputForm
(* Style["Test", FontWeight :> If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Bold, Plain]] *)

Note that alternatively, you can use Dynamic, which is the mechanism that is also used, for example, in hyperlinks:
CurrentValue[{"StyleDefinitions", "HyperlinkDefault"}] // InputForm
(* {..., DefaultBaseStyle -> Dynamic[If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
          {"HyperlinkActive"}, {"Hyperlink"}], ...}



Would be nice to know the details of evaluation of the two approaches (:> and Dynamic), as it is not trivial, even for the seasoned mind.

@IstvánZachar, both of the approaches result in a StyleBox, and all of the dynamics is then handled by the front-end (without the main kernel), which is a beast on its own ...

The Dynamic version would be the preferred variation.  The RuleDelayed version works in this instance, thanks to CurrentValue.  If it was a regular kernel variable, the result should be pretty self-explanatory.
